# SVN Tree Errors

Tags: svn, tree-conflict

I am new to SVN and I think I made some errors I am not sure how to fix. I am uploading my plugins to WordPress. I uploaded a few versions, then realized that there was a file that I was developing that was not ready and causing issues. So I removed the file from the Trunk folder and the tags version folder and now I am getting the following errors. Seems that no matter what I do I can not fix it.

When I do svn stat I get:

```
?       bh-design
!     C tags/1.0/widgets/email-subscription
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
!     C tags/1.1/widgets/email-subscription
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
?       tags/1.2
!       tags/1.4
!       tags/1.4/assets
!M      tags/1.4/assets/screenshot-1.png
!M      tags/1.4/assets/screenshot-2.png
!M      tags/1.4/assets/screenshot-3.png
!M      tags/1.4/bhdesign-font-demo.html
!       tags/1.4/bhdesign-plugin.css
!       tags/1.4/bhdesign-plugin.php
!       tags/1.4/css
!       tags/1.4/css/bh-login.css
!M      tags/1.4/css/featherlight.min.css
!       tags/1.4/fonts
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/Read Me.txt
!       tags/1.4/fonts/demo-files
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/demo-files/demo.css
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/demo-files/demo.js
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.eot
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.svg
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.ttf
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.woff
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/selection.json
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/style.css
!       tags/1.4/images
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-help.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-icon.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-login-logo.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-add-image.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-add-widget.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-categories-tags.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-comment-spam.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-create-link.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-create-page.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-create-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-custom-menu.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-dashboard-login.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-dashboard-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-disable-trackbacks.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-distraction-free.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-edit-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-embed-video.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-lovation-currency-measurements.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-manage-orders.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-media.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-product-variations.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-settings-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-shipping-methods.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-user.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-woocommerce-products.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bluehost-info-sheet.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/help-thumb-template.psd
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-help.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-icon.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-login-logo.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-add-image.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-add-widget.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-categories-tags.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-comment-spam.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-create-link.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-create-page.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-create-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-custom-menu.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-dashboard-login.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-dashboard-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-disable-trackbacks.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-distraction-free.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-edit-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-embed-video.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-lovation-currency-measurements.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-manage-orders.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-media.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-product-variations.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-settings-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-shipping-methods.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-user.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-woocommerce-products.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-help.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-icon.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-login-logo.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-add-image.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-add-widget.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-categories-tags.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-comment-spam.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-create-link.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-create-page.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-create-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-custom-menu.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-dashboard-login.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-dashboard-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-disable-trackbacks.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-distraction-free.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-edit-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-embed-video.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-lovation-currency-measurements.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-manage-orders.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-media.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-product-variations.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-settings-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-shipping-methods.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-user.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-woocommerce-products.png
!       tags/1.4/includes
!       tags/1.4/includes/login-screen.php
!       tags/1.4/includes/options-page-wrapper.php
!       tags/1.4/js
!M      tags/1.4/js/featherlight.min.js
!       tags/1.4/readme.txt
!       tags/1.4/widgets
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/inc
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/inc/options.php
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/inc/output.php
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/social-icons.php
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/style.css
M       trunk/bhdesign-plugin.php
M       trunk/readme.txt
?     C trunk/widgets/email-subscription
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 3
```

When I try and submit the plugin doing svn ci -m 'notes'   I get:

```
?       bh-design
!     C tags/1.0/widgets/email-subscription
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
!     C tags/1.1/widgets/email-subscription
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
?       tags/1.2
!       tags/1.4
!       tags/1.4/assets
!M      tags/1.4/assets/screenshot-1.png
!M      tags/1.4/assets/screenshot-2.png
!M      tags/1.4/assets/screenshot-3.png
!M      tags/1.4/bhdesign-font-demo.html
!       tags/1.4/bhdesign-plugin.css
!       tags/1.4/bhdesign-plugin.php
!       tags/1.4/css
!       tags/1.4/css/bh-login.css
!M      tags/1.4/css/featherlight.min.css
!       tags/1.4/fonts
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/Read Me.txt
!       tags/1.4/fonts/demo-files
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/demo-files/demo.css
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/demo-files/demo.js
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.eot
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.svg
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.ttf
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.woff
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/selection.json
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/style.css
!       tags/1.4/images
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-help.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-icon.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-login-logo.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-add-image.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-add-widget.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-categories-tags.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-comment-spam.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-create-link.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-create-page.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-create-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-custom-menu.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-dashboard-login.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-dashboard-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-disable-trackbacks.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-distraction-free.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-edit-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-embed-video.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-lovation-currency-measurements.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-manage-orders.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-media.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-product-variations.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-settings-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-shipping-methods.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-user.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-woocommerce-products.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bluehost-info-sheet.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/help-thumb-template.psd
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-help.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-icon.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-login-logo.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-add-image.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-add-widget.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-categories-tags.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-comment-spam.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-create-link.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-create-page.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-create-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-custom-menu.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-dashboard-login.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-dashboard-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-disable-trackbacks.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-distraction-free.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-edit-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-embed-video.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-lovation-currency-measurements.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-manage-orders.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-media.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-product-variations.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-settings-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-shipping-methods.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-user.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-woocommerce-products.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-help.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-icon.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-login-logo.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-add-image.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-add-widget.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-categories-tags.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-comment-spam.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-create-link.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-create-page.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-create-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-custom-menu.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-dashboard-login.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-dashboard-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-disable-trackbacks.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-distraction-free.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-edit-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-embed-video.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-lovation-currency-measurements.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-manage-orders.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-media.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-product-variations.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-settings-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-shipping-methods.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-user.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-woocommerce-products.png
!       tags/1.4/includes
!       tags/1.4/includes/login-screen.php
!       tags/1.4/includes/options-page-wrapper.php
!       tags/1.4/js
!M      tags/1.4/js/featherlight.min.js
!       tags/1.4/readme.txt
!       tags/1.4/widgets
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/inc
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/inc/options.php
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/inc/output.php
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/social-icons.php
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/style.css
M       trunk/bhdesign-plugin.php
M       trunk/readme.txt
?     C trunk/widgets/email-subscription
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 3
10-200-8-78:bh-design brturpin$ svn stat
?       bh-design
!     C tags/1.0/widgets/email-subscription
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
!     C tags/1.1/widgets/email-subscription
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
?       tags/1.2
!       tags/1.4
!       tags/1.4/assets
!M      tags/1.4/assets/screenshot-1.png
!M      tags/1.4/assets/screenshot-2.png
!M      tags/1.4/assets/screenshot-3.png
!M      tags/1.4/bhdesign-font-demo.html
!       tags/1.4/bhdesign-plugin.css
!       tags/1.4/bhdesign-plugin.php
!       tags/1.4/css
!       tags/1.4/css/bh-login.css
!M      tags/1.4/css/featherlight.min.css
!       tags/1.4/fonts
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/Read Me.txt
!       tags/1.4/fonts/demo-files
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/demo-files/demo.css
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/demo-files/demo.js
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.eot
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.svg
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.ttf
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/icomoon.woff
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/selection.json
!M      tags/1.4/fonts/style.css
!       tags/1.4/images
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-help.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-icon.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-login-logo.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-add-image.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-add-widget.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-categories-tags.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-comment-spam.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-create-link.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-create-page.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-create-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-custom-menu.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-dashboard-login.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-dashboard-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-disable-trackbacks.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-distraction-free.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-edit-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-embed-video.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-lovation-currency-measurements.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-manage-orders.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-media.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-product-variations.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-settings-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-shipping-methods.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-user.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bh-video-woocommerce-products.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/bluehost-info-sheet.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/help-thumb-template.psd
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-help.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-icon.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-login-logo.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-add-image.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-add-widget.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-categories-tags.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-comment-spam.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-create-link.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-create-page.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-create-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-custom-menu.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-dashboard-login.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-dashboard-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-disable-trackbacks.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-distraction-free.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-edit-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-embed-video.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-lovation-currency-measurements.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-manage-orders.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-media.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-product-variations.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-settings-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-shipping-methods.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-user.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/hm-video-woocommerce-products.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-help.jpg
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-icon.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-login-logo.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-add-image.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-add-widget.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-categories-tags.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-comment-spam.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-create-link.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-create-page.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-create-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-custom-menu.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-dashboard-login.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-dashboard-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-disable-trackbacks.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-distraction-free.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-edit-post.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-embed-video.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-lovation-currency-measurements.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-manage-orders.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-media.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-product-variations.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-settings-overview.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-shipping-methods.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-user.png
!M      tags/1.4/images/jh-video-woocommerce-products.png
!       tags/1.4/includes
!       tags/1.4/includes/login-screen.php
!       tags/1.4/includes/options-page-wrapper.php
!       tags/1.4/js
!M      tags/1.4/js/featherlight.min.js
!       tags/1.4/readme.txt
!       tags/1.4/widgets
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/inc
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/inc/options.php
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/inc/output.php
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/social-icons.php
!       tags/1.4/widgets/social-icons/style.css
M       trunk/bhdesign-plugin.php
M       trunk/readme.txt
?     C trunk/widgets/email-subscription
      >   local delete, incoming delete upon update
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 3
10-200-8-78:bh-design brturpin$ svn ci -m 'Version 1.2'
svn: E155015: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E155015: Aborting commit: '/Users/brturpin/Sites/wordpress-org/bh-design/tags/1.0/widgets/email-subscription' remains in conflict
```

You can view what is there now here: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/bh-design/tags/

There are a bunch of errors regarding tags/1.4/* and the email subscription folder that I removed. The issue is there is no tags/1.4/ on my local machine, and when I do svn up it does not add it, so I am not sure where this 1.4 is....

Any help will be good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to delete everything from the SVN and start over from scratch.